# Get child items with date filetypes using regex in Powershell

Tags: regex, powershell

I am dealing with many files that have a file extension such as .20180615 (yyyyMMDD). I am looking for a way to access all files with a date filetype using regex. The only solution I have right now is to use *2 to get all files with a filetype starting with 2, but I would prefer a solution that used regex to generalize across all dates in the yyyyMMDD format.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse *2
```

Comment: With `Get-ChildItem` you can use `[0-9]` ranges aside from wildcards `*?` I.e. `Get-ChildItem *.20[01][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]`

Comment: `*2` will bind to the filter parameter of `Get-ChildItem` That should only match files then end in 2. Note that `-Filter` also matches against shornames so that could be affecting the output as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are *many* solutions to this issue. Most choices could just be based on personal preference but there could be performance and validation limitations concerns.

When dealing with files it is always more suitable to try and use the built-in filtering as opposed to post-processing with `Where-Object` and the like. It affects performance especially when `-recurse` is involved. The limitation is basic wildcard support for `Get-ChildItem -Path`. So, with that in mind, [LotPings comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50880822/get-child-items-with-date-filetypes-using-regex-in-powershell#comment88764088_50880822) covers that solution.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "$path\*.20[01][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]" -Recurse
```

You should be covered until the year 2099!

---

You tagged regex so a simple `Where-Object` filter for that would just be

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object{$_.Extension -match '^\d{8}$'}
```

Lacks some validation but if the extension is 8 digits you are good to go.

---

Another approach that validates your criteria better would be to only allow files with valid dates

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse | Where-Object{
    try{
        [datetime]::ParseExact($_.Extension,"yyyyMMdd",[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::InvariantCulture)
    } catch {
        $false
    }
} | ForEach-Object{
    # Do stuff
}
```

If there is a valid date in the extension that file (or folder) will get passed down the pipeline. That being said if you have at least psv3 consider the `-File` switch for `Get-ChildItem`.

Comment: The last approach, using ParseExact, is the only one that will ensure only valid dates are used. The other approaches could allow files having eight (8) digits, but which might not be a valid date.

Comment: @lit Hands down yes. I was trying to talk about that in the beginning. Its up to how much the OP trusts the data. Simplicity vs. Integrity

Comment: Is there any way to use [0-9] from your first approach but without using filter? Something along the lines of Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse *20[01][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]. I ask because somehow using filter gives me a different output; might be because of my setup

Comment: @Nate That string should still bind to `Filter` so the difference should not exist. does it change anything if you quote it?

Comment: If I use Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Filter '*.20[01][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9]' -Recurse
it doesn't find any of the same files as Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse *2 (even though you'd think it should). I know the [0-9] range will be needed, but it seems the only way for it to work as desired would be to do Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse *[0-9], but that doesn't replicate Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Recurse *2 either (the only files with numeric filetypes start with 2, so no issues there). Is there a way for me to use [0-9] without using Filter?

Comment: @Nate I think part of the issue is that `-filter` will also match against short file names. So you might have muddy waters easily with that `cmd /c dir c:\temp /x`. I also made a mistake. Filter does not support the character ranges. Only the path does.

Comment: That fixed it! Appreciate your thorough help tremendously!